# How to load the chat application in an iframe without using the <iframe> tag?

Tags: javascript, chat, botframework, chatbot, direct-line-botframework

I am trying to make a multi tenant Chatbot application using microsoft's Bot Framework webchat, So I want my clients to include this kind of code which I think is standard for such applications:

```
<script src="link to the cdn" ></script> 
<script> 
    BotfuelWebChat.init({ appToken: '444107', 
    size: { width: 500, height: 600 }, 
    startOpen: false,
    startFullScreen: false, 
      theme: { colors: { background: '#faf3db', main: '#244891', 
      primary: '#0084f4' }, layout: { compact: false, rounded: false, 
      shadowed: false, noHeader: false, noBorder: false, 
      noHelpMessage: false } } }); 
</script>
```

Now my question is what javascript or jquery code should be written in the CDN included above such that my application gets loaded in the chatbox of the client.

I am using Node.js for backend of the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for your reference, and for more the details your requirements, I think you should implememnt yourself.

```
var BotfuelWebChat = {
    init:(options)=>{
        const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id='bot';
        div.style.width =options.size.width+"px";
        div.style.height =options.size.height+"px";
        div.style.position ="relative";
        document.body.appendChild(div);

        BotChat.App({
              bot: {id: 'botid'},
              locale: params['locale'],
              resize: 'detect',
              user: {id:'userid'},
              directLine: {
                secret: options.appSecret,
                token: options.appToken
              }
            }, div);
        }
}
```

And in your html script:

```
<script>

    BotfuelWebChat.init({
      appToken:'directline secret',
      size: { width: 500, height: 600 }
      })
    </script>
```

Comment: This really helps, I just had a question that I want to send the details directline token and secret from my own server but the html script like above will be running in the client's server, so I cant understand how will the chatbot be loaded, I mean how will it get new token?

Hope I make myself clear

Comment: Yes, you can generate the token in your server https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication#generate-token for your client requesting.

Comment: I am very sorry for not understanding but i know how to generate tokens but where i am actually facing problem is when i generate token from my server and render the page i do not have the script mentioned and when call it using the script then i am not able to get the token..  so basically i am struggling with the structure of application. Like how at the same time generate the token from my server and render the app into some other server. I am sorry if i still sounds unclear.

Comment: You can explore the genrating token function as an API in your server, and in the web site client, before you init the bot chat instantiation, you call the backed API for the token, then instantiate the bot chat with this token.